# Can we split a string using STRING_SPLIT() in WHERE clause to compare the same with more than one value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Can we split a string using STRING_SPLIT() in WHERE clause to compare the same with more than one value? It will be more clear with my query. Please check it below.

**Table1**

```
| columnA | columnB |
| ------- | ------- |
|    1    |  A,B,C  |
|    2    |  A,B    |
|    3    |  B,C    |
```

**Table2**

```
|  value  |  
| ------- |
|    A    |
|    B    |
|    C    |
```

I tried the below query, but it didn't work.

```
select * from Table1 where STRING_SPLIT(columnB,',') IN (select value from Table2)
```

Thanks

Comment: string split returns a table value, not a scalar. So its not supported. You need to look at some of the JOIN options in the the answer below

Comment: *Really*, what you should be doing is fixing your desogn. Don't store delimited data in the first place.

Comment: Can you show what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```sql
    select t1.*
    from Table1 t1 cross apply
         string_split(t1.b, ',') s join
         table2 t2
         on t2.value = s.value;
```

Or a subquery:

```sql
    select t1.*
    from table1 t1
    where exists (select 1
                  from string_split(t1.b, ',') s join
                       table2 t2
                       on t2.value = s.value;
                 );
```

But you should really fix your data model so you are not storing multiple values in a string column.

Comment: What happen if I replace Table2 with CTE?

Comment: `JOIN {Some Table}` and `JOIN {CTE}` are no different syntax wise, @HKRich

Comment: I suspect OP wants the second option

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

(Doesn't use `STRING_SPLIT` function)

```
select * from Table1 
inner join Table2 on ',' + Table1.ColumnB + ',' like '%,' + Table2.Value + ',%'
```

Not sure about performance. You would need to time it yourself.